# Running gpiozero listener continuously with uvicorn

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-socketio, uvicorn, gpiozero

I am trying to write a python app that will run on raspberry pi, that will have both socket connection (socketio with uvicorn) and physical input listeners. I intend to listen for socket connection and gpio events concurrently, without blocking each other. This is what I have so far:

`api.py`

```
import uvicorn
import asyncio
from interaction.volume import VolumeControl
from system.platform_info import PlatformInfo
from connection.api_socket import app


class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def initialize_volume_listener(self):
        volume_controller = VolumeControl()
        volume_controller.start_listener()

    def start(self):
        PlatformInfo().print_info()
        self.initialize_volume_listener()
        uvicorn.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, loop="asyncio")
```

`volume_control.py`

```
import asyncio
from gpiozero import Button
from connection.api_socket import volume_up


class VolumeControl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.volume_up_button = Button(4)

    def volume_up(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(volume_up(None, None))
        loop.run_until_complete(future)
        loop.close()

    def start_listener(self):
        self.volume_up_button.when_pressed = self.volume_up
```

`api_socket.py`

```
import socketio
from system.platform_info import PlatformInfo

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = socketio.ASGIApp(sio)


@sio.on('connect')
async def test_connect(sid, environ):
    system_info = PlatformInfo().get_info()
    current_volume = 35
    initial_data = {"system_info": system_info,
                    "settings": {"volume": current_volume}
                    }
    await sio.emit('initial_data', initial_data, room=sid)


@sio.on('disconnect request')
async def disconnect_request(sid):
    await sio.disconnect(sid)


@sio.on('disconnect')
async def test_disconnect(sid):
    print('Client disconnected')
    await sio.emit('disconnect', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0}, room=sid)


@sio.on('volume_up')
async def volume_up(sid, volume=None):
    increased_volume = 25
    await sio.emit('volume_up', {'volume': increased_volume})


@sio.on('volume_down')
async def volume_down(sid, volume=None):
    decreased_volume = 25
    await sio.emit('volume_down', {'volume': decreased_volume})
```

I have tried using asyncio, but I am kind of new on async features of python. The problem is that, I wasn't able to run the button listener continuously, so that while socket functions are in progress, I would be able to concurrently listen for button interactions, without blocking one another. The button listener does not work at all. Instead, I need the button listener to be running as long as the uvicorn app is up.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is gpiozero an asyncio compatible library? I suspect it isn't, so your only hope is to put it in a separate thread that is not running an asyncio loop. Even with this you may face trouble when trying to communicate between the gpio and asyncio threads. My recommendation is that you look for an asyncio compatible gpio library.

Comment: @Miguel again, thank you for your answer. I would like to clarify one more issue. Considering the limited resources on a raspberry pi device, would it be better for performance to implement a server using flask, rather than uvicorn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Miguel thank you for your answer. As you suggested, I have started the gpio in a `while` loop and used `asyncio.run()` command inside the loop to call the related socketio function. It works as intended. Side Note: I have started the gpio thread with param `daemon=True`. This enables to quit the gpio loop as soon as I quit the main thread, which is the uvicorn server. Final code is as follows:

`api_socket.py`

```
@sio.on('video_load')
async def load_video(sid, video_number=3):
    data = open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f'sample_videos/dummy_video_{str(video_number)}.mp4'), 'rb').read()
    print('Streaming video...')
    await sio.emit('video_load', {'source': data}, room=sid)
```

`nfc_listener.py`

```
class NFCListener:

    reading = True

    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        self.rdr = RFID()
        util = self.rdr.util()
        util.debug = True
        self.listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_nfc, daemon=True)

    def start_nfc(self):
        selected_video = None
        while self.reading:
            self.rdr.wait_for_tag()
            (error, data) = self.rdr.request()
            if not error:
                print("\nCard identified!")
                (error, uid) = self.rdr.anticoll()
                if not error:
                    # Print UID
                    card_uid = str(uid[0])+" "+str(uid[1])+" " + \
                        str(uid[2])+" "+str(uid[3])+" "+str(uid[4])
                    print(card_uid)
                    if card_uid == "166 107 86 20 143":
                        if selected_video != 2:
                            selected_video = 2
                            asyncio.run(load_video(None, selected_video))
                    else:
                        if selected_video != 3:
                            selected_video = 3
                            asyncio.run(load_video(None, selected_video))

    def start_reading(self):
        self.listener_thread.start()
```

Comment: This works *BUT* creates 2 asyncio loops and executes the callback in a different thread. This may cause problems with libraries which are not threadsafe (and most asyncio libraries will, of course, make no effort at all to be threadsafe).
Use loop.call_soon_threadsafe() as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

gpiozero creates a new thread which executes the callback (this isn't documented very well). If the callback should be executed in the main asyncio loop then you need to pass control back to the main thread.

The [call_soon_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) method does that for you. Essentially it adds the callback to the list of tasks the main asyncio loop calls when an await happens.

However asyncio loops are local to each thread: see [get_running_loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#)

So when the gpiozero object is created in the main asyncio thread then you need make that loop object available to the object when the callback is called.

Here's how I do that for a PIR that calls an asyncio MQTT method:

```
class PIR:
    def __init__(self, mqtt, pin):
        self.pir = MotionSensor(pin=pin)
        self.pir.when_motion = self.motion
        # store the mqtt client we'll need to call
        self.mqtt = mqtt
        # This PIR object is created in the main thread
        # so store that loop object
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    def motion(self):
        # motion is called in the gpiozero monitoring thread
        # it has to use our stored copy of the loop and then
        # tell that loop to call the callback:
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.mqtt.publish,
                                       f'sensor/gpiod/pir/kitchen', True)
```

You probably want this:

```
import asyncio
from gpiozero import Button
from connection.api_socket import volume_up

class VolumeControl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.volume_up_button = Button(4)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    def volume_up_cb(self):
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(volume_up, None, None)

    def start_listener(self):
        self.volume_up_button.when_pressed = self.volume_up_cb
```

Much cleaner - and threadsafe! :)